# Distribution of Key value pairs in Jboss Data Grid

Tags: caching, jboss, infinispan

I am loading 20 million non expiry entries in the Jboss Data Grid using Hotrod clients. My Hot rod clients are running on 5 different machines to load the data. The entries got added successfully. We have given a replication factor of 2. So there will be total 40 million entries in the grid. We found a variation of more than  10 % in the no of entries being added in each node. For eg, One node has 7.8 million entries while other node has 12 million entries.

So I was thinking why the entries are not equally distributed, ideally each node should have about 10 million entries. Our objective of the above test was to check whether the load/requests are getting equally distributed on all the nodes.

Any pointers on how the key/value pairs are distributed in JDG would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Infinispan the hash space is divided into segments which then get mapped to the nodes in the cluster.
Entries are hashed by their keys by applying the MurmurHash3 function to them. This determines the segment which owns the key. It could be possible that your keys are causing a somewhat uneven distribution. You could try increasing the number of segments in your configuration. With your cluster, use at least 100 segments.
Also I had to lookup the meaning of "crore" and "lakh", as I had no idea what they were. You should probably use the 10M and 100K notations instead to make it easier to understand.